# Error in model prediction with lme

Tags: r

I'm trying to make predictions from my lme-model:

```
mod<-lme(height~direction+time+distnest+loop+twc+twc:direction,random=~1|bird_id/FT_no,data=dat,correlation=corAR1(0.5))
```

Unfortunately I have a nested random and 5 fixed effects and do not really know how to handle them all.

All fixed effects are numeric, except "direction" and "time", which are two-level factors ("land" or "sea"; "day" or "night").

For model prediction I've tried the following:

```
newdat<-data.frame(loop=seq(min(dat$loop),max(dat$loop),length=100),
               direction=factor("land",levels(dat$direction)),
               time_code=factor("1",levels(dat$time)),
               distnest=mean(dat$distnest),
               twc=mean(dat$twc))

newdat$pred<-predict(mod,newdata=newdat,level=0)
plot(dat$loop,dat$height,pch=16,las=1,cex.lab=1.2)
lines(newdat$loop,yhat,lwd=2) ### for plotting one of the fixed effects
newdat$predse<-predict(mod,newdat,se.fit=TRUE)$se.fit
```

But when using the se.fit=TRUE there is an error: "Error in predict.lme(mod3, newdat, se.fit = TRUE) : cannot evaluate groups for desired levels on 'newdata'"

Does se.fit not work for lmes? Omitting the level=0 did not work. Is the code wrong?

I also tried the code from glmm.wikidot:

```
newdat<-expand.grid(direction=c("land","sea"),time_code=c("1","2"),loop30=c(0.08,1),distne    st=c(0.01,99.43),twc=c(-56.88744,57.93735))
newdat$pred<-predict(mod3,newdat,level=0)
Designmat <- model.matrix(eval(eval(mod3$call$fixed)[-2]), newdat[-ncol(newdat)]) 
predvar <- diag(Designmat %*% mod3$varFix %*% t(Designmat)) 
newdat$SE <- sqrt(predvar) 
newdat$SE2 <- sqrt(predvar+mod3$sigma^2)
library(ggplot2) 
pd <- position_dodge(width=0.4) 
g0 <- ggplot(newdat,aes(x=loop30,y=pred,colour=direction))+ 
geom_point(position=pd) 
g0 + geom_linerange(aes(ymin=pred-2*SE,ymax=pred+2*SE), position=pd)
## prediction intervals 
g0 + geom_linerange(aes(ymin=pred-2*SE2,ymax=pred+2*SE2), position=pd)
```

But the plot is completely wrong. Can anyone help me with the correct code? Thanks a lot in advance.

Best wishes, Anna

Comment: Without some actual data, hard.

Comment: `predict.lme` doesn't have an `se.fit` parameter. However, passing one doesn't have any effect. The error results from omitting `level=0` and not providing the grouping variables for the random intercept. Your error description for the second approach ("plot is completely wrong") doesn't allow diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

For prediction you need all of the items in the RHS of your model ...  _as_named_ :

```
direction + time + distnest + loop + twc 
...and...  bird_id ...and... FT_no
```

At the moment you have misnamed the `time` variable as `time_code` and failed to include either of your "random effects" variables. Here's the relevant bit from nlme::lme's help page: " All variables used in the fixed and random effects models, as well as the grouping factors, must be present in the data frame. If missing, the fitted values are returned."